# Not able to create elastic search index using nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I tried creating elasticsearch index in node.js but I always get the exception:

```
status: 405,
  displayName: 'MethodNotAllowed',
  message:
   'Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/anil] and method [POST], allowed: [DELETE, PUT, GET, HEAD]' } { error:
   'Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/anil] and method [POST], allowed: [DELETE, PUT, GET, HEAD]',
  status: 405 } 405
```

Search, getmapping, index exists functions are working fine but not the create index.

```
(function () {
    const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
    const esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: '127.0.0.1:9200',
        log: 'error'
    });
    const indices = function indices() {
        esClient.indices.exists({
            index: 'anil'
        }, (err, res, status) = > {
            if (res) {
                console.log('index already exists');
            } else {
                //tring to create index but not working
                esClient.indices.create({
                    index: 'anil'
                }, (err, res, status) = > {
                    console.log(err, res, status);
                })
            }
        });
    };
    // only for testing purposes
    // all calls should be initiated through the module
    const test = function test() {
        console.log(`elasticsearch indices information: `);
        indices();
    };
    test();
    module.exports = {
        indices
    };
}());
```

Please help how can I create the elasticsearch index using nodejs

Comment: your index creation code seems fine ` //tring to create index but not working
                esClient.indices.create({
                    index: 'anil'
                }, (err, res, status) = > {
                    console.log(err, res, status);
                })` ...it is complaining about you using `POST`? is this `express route` that has  `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **elasticsearch** configurations by adding these lines then restart **elasticsearch** and try again:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
```